# C# Crystal Report Excel Export Formatting issue

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-2008

I've a crystal report which have two sections. i.e. summary and details section.

When I export the report in excel via code below:

```
ReportExporter.FormatType = CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.Excel;
```

The formatting of the report is not correct. i.e. the detail section is not aligned to detail heading the cells are merged incorrectly instead.

Could anyone please help me whether there is anyway to fix this issue? i.e. render the detail on separate sheet or preserver the formatting etc?

Answer (score 0):

Try using ExportFormatType.ExcelRecord instead. It will layout the report according to the cells in the spreadsheet.  You lose a little of the formatting though.

Comment: Thank you but this is not acceptable solution for business. Theywould like the reprot nicely formatted including heading. just like what it appears on PDF